# Save value from textbox(where value is displayed on being fetched from DB) in DB using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, save

I have a form, which has multiple text boxes. For one such text box,I fetch the data from DB and display the value in the text box using the echo statement.

However, after filling up the entire form and clicking submit, there is values in all the text boxes except this one.

I am using PDO and saving the value in MySQL Db. I am very new to PHP and am unable to figure this out!!

My Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])=="Save") {
   $RestName = $_POST['username'];
   if (empty($RestName))
      echo "Restname is empty";
   else
      echo "Restname is not empty";
}

?>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
<?php

$STM = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM vendorusers WHERE vd_user_email=:email");

$STM->bindParam(':email',$email);
$STM->execute();
$rows = $STM->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row) { 
  $username = $row['vd_user_name'];
?>

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id = "username" name = "username" value= "<?php echo $username; ?>">

<?php  } ?>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value = "Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Save</button>
</form>
```

This code displays that "Restname is empty";

How do I get the value (fetched from DB and displayed in textbox) during the submit?

Answer (score 0):

Please change name of input name='username' to name='username[]'.Use array in name for get multiple result.

Answer (score 0):

The test using `isset` is wrong - you would need to change that to something like `if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit']=='Save' ) {` etc or use `empty` as that does an implicit `isset` as below.

```
<?php

    $RestName = !empty( $_POST["submit"] ) && $_POST["submit"]=='Save' && !empty( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
    echo $RestName ? "Restname is empty" : "Restname is not empty";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks... But can u tell me how to populate the value in the $Restname while submitting. Cz the echo statement in the value is displaying the value in the screen, but not storing it in the value field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the $restname` var is set in the above statement if it exists in the POST array, otherwise it is set to false.